# htaccess and ampersand in the URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a table where each row represents a page. The column `title` holds the page name. When loading the page, the original url looked like this: `www.mysite.com/?q=france`, I then do a quick DB lookup `WHERE title = 'france'` and that's it. I'm now using htaccess to make the url's friendlier. like so: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9#%@\s\(\)\[\]\-]+)$ page.php?q=$1`, so I can use `www.mysite.com/france`. The problem I have is when the title has an ampersand, like 'one & two'. The lookup fails. I tried

1. adding `\&` to the htaccess, and
2. www.mysite.com/one %26 two

Both of these fail, although `www.mysite.com/?q=one %26 two` does work.

Is there any way for me to get this to work with the "clean" urls?

TIA!

Comment: http://dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/

Comment: Although I got my answer, I'm curious as to why this question is considered off topic. I've looked at the FAQ linked below, and the question seems to be within the scope. I'd gladly reword it if someone would tell me where the problem lies...

Comment: i fail to see how this can be off topic as well...

Comment: @WouterJ Let your friends know :-)

Comment: @Phil I have marked it as 'reopen', but I saw others marked it as closed... (http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1642839 ) You can create a question at meta.stackoverflow.com to see what the 'hardcore SO members & mods' think of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things:

1. URI's are decoded before it's put through mod_rewrite, so you don't want to match against `%26`, you want to simply match against `&`.
2. You now need to *re-encode* the `&` back to `%26` because it's being placed in the query string, so you need to use the `B` flag. So something like this:

   ```
   # Add a "&"----------------v
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9#%@&\s\(\)\[\]\-]+)$ page.php?q=$1 [L,B]
   #                     Include the "B" flag -------------------^
   ```